# Asterisk Libjansson package missing

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, asterisk

I'm faced with a problem. I don't know what to do next:

> asterisk: error while loading shared libraries: libjansson.so.4:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: `yum install jansson-devel`

Answer (score 0):

First try just run

```
ldd
```

If not help, try find  libjansson.so.4. If found, ensure it is in path. If not found, try  libjansson.so*(any other version) and do symlink to  libjansson.so.4.

Answer (score 0):

First have the required release of jansson :
untar is and run (if already installed then skip this part)

```
./configure
make
make check
make install
```

ldconfig creates the necessary links to the runtime libraries, you need to create a config file and add the path of the library of your choice.

```
echo “/usr/local/lib” > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/usr_local.conf
/sbin/ldconfig
```

reference : [this](http://www.danjourno.com/asterisk-libjansson-cannot-open-shared/)